# How can I show border with css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for my layout , trying to show a border at the bottom of the div:

```
<div class="row small headerheight borderbottom hidden-xs">
    <div class="col-md-8 headerheight vcenteritems paditems">Items</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 headerheight vcenteritems light-grey hcenteritems borderright">One-off</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 headerheight vcenteritems light-grey hcenteritems">Monthly</div>
</div>
```

The borderbottom is only showing a border for the first column:

```
.borderbottom
{
  border-bottom: solid 1px #b3b3b3 ;
}
```

How can I display an border for the one off and monthly column too?

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/ENeMwm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the border to any `div` that is inside `.borderbottom`:

```
.borderbottom div
{
    border-bottom: solid 1px #b3b3b3 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just got done having this same discussion with our team. Don't set `height` unless you absolutely need to. Remember that. What you are not seeing is that the grey boxes are covering up the border which is in fact spanning the entire width. The reason this is happening is because the grey boxes have a fixed height set to them when they don't need to. Again:

> Do not set the `height` of something unless there is absolutely no other way.

Instead, let the padding-top, padding-bottom, font-size, and line-height determine the height. Play with those numbers until you reach a satisfactory height.

I found that padding top and bottom of `20px` did the trick (as well as removing the 60px fixed height). Here's a basic example:

```
<div class="header-row">
    <div>Items</div>
    <div>One-off</div>
    <div>Monthly</div>
</div>

.header-row > * {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```